# Complex subquery with cakephp3's ORM

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a pretty complex (fancy?) query, which is working in pure sql but I need to translate it to be used with cakephp 3.0's orm.

This is the query:

```sql
select user_id, count(id)/period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'),
date_format(sent, '%Y%m')) AS average from invoices 
WHERE sent != '0000-00-00' GROUP BY user_id
```

And this is what I was trying:

```
$monthly = $this->find()
  ->select(function ($query) {
    return [
      'user_id',
      'average' => $query->func()->extract(
        'COUNT(Invoices.id)/PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(now(), "%Y%m"),
         date_format(Invoices.sent, "%Y%m"))'
      )
    ];
  })
  ->where([
    "Invoices.sent !=" => "0000-00-00",
  ])
  ->group('user_id');
```

The problem is, the extract method (which I'm not sure it's what I actually need) is available [since CakePHP 3.1](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html), but I'm using 3.0.

Is it the correct method? Can I make it work with 3.0 somehow, or is there something else I can use?

Comment: Is upgrading to 3.1 out of the question? Incompatibilities are pretty minimal...

Comment: Your raw SQL query doesn't use `EXTRACT`, so why would you try to use  this with the query builder?

Comment: I can't upgrade to 3.1 because of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757870/respond-as-xml-not-working-since-cakephp-3-1)[another problem] that I had previously.
Anyway, I have managed to make it work with a raw expression: `$query->newExpr()->add('.......')`.