# How to echo sitemap.xml Cakephp3.1

Tags: php, cakephp, mime-types, cakephp-3.0, sitemap

I am having trouble setting a mime-type in the `sitemapxml.xml`. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757870/respond-as-xml-not-working-since-cakephp-3-1), but it has no effect:

```
$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
$this->response->header(['Content-type' => 'application/xml']);
```

I also tried to add `header('Content-type:text/xml')` at the beginning of my sitemap.ctp view.

Comment: Please always add proper context, in this case, mention where exactly your code snippet is located in your controller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the migration guide:

> `RequestHandlerComponent` now switches the layout and template based on the parsed extension or `Accept` header in the `beforeRender()` callback instead of `startup()`.

**[Cookbook > Appendices > 3.1 Migration Guide > RequestHandlerComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-1-migration-guide.html#requesthandlercomponent)**

So this means that what you set there (wherever that is, but for sure it's not in the `Controller::beforeRender()` callback), will be overwritten after the controller action ran, and before the view is being rendered.

There are various ways to handle this.

1. Make proper use of the request handler component, that is, enable extension parsing and supply an extension in your URL, or send a proper `Accept` header. That way the component will set the proper response type.

   This is the recommended way!

   See also **[Cookbook > Views > JSON and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)**
2. Set the `RequestHandlerComponent::$ext` property, which is being evaluated before rendering, and will cause the request handler component to set the response type accordingly,

   ```
   $this->RequestHandler->ext = 'xml';
   ```
3. Use `RequestHandlerComponent::renderAs()` to instruct the request handler component to use the configured XML view, which will override the "wrong" type set in the `beforeRender()` callback.

   ```
   $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml');
   ```
4. Do not use the request handler component and set the response type directly on the response object.

   ```
   $this->response->type('xml');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Intersting, I've saw that `$this->response->type` works
only if `$this->render('view');` is set directly